# Stuff function with For XML

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT DISTINCT PCode.EventID,
    stuff((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + E.ProcedureCode  from SXAESEventProcedureCode E where E.EventID = PCode.EventID 
    FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') ProcedureCode  
From SXAESEventProcedureCode PCode
```

Above is the script, rather using the stuff function, how can i convert it into comma seperated. Is there any way to replace distinct function, though i need  unique Eventid with comma seperated Procedure code.

This query is taking almost 95% of the cost of the execution Plan.

Comment: Replace it with what? We have no idea what you are trying to do here. It sounds like it is maybe part of a larger procedure or query? Here is a great place to start improving this question so others will be able to help. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Not really, no. There are other ways to serialize data into a CSV, but most are slower and/or more complicated. You can use `GROUP BY` instead of `DISTINCT`, but I'd be surprised if doing so got you any difference in performance.

Comment: Thanks by adding group by instead of distinct, the plan has improved.

Answer (score 1):

STUFF together with FOR XML PATH is used to concatenate rows into a single column. I have used it with large data sets with amazing performance. I would imagine that this is *not* the issue here, rather it is the indexing, or lack thereof, in your tables.

Please share your execution plan with us so that index issue can be pointed out. Use this link for easy sharing: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/